# Eloquent with declared table to use in the query

Tags: sql-server, laravel, sql-server-2005, eloquent

Given Larvel 5.2 and a SQL Server 2005 database. I have query something like this:

```
declare @mapping_table table(id int, name varchar(255), mapping_value varchar(255))

insert into @mapping_table values (1, 'foo', 'A1')
insert into @mapping_table values (2, 'bar', 'A1')
insert into @mapping_table values (3, 'baz', 'A2')

select distinct(lookup_field) 
from production_table
where lookup_field not in (
  select name
  from @mapping_table 
)
```

When I run this using Eloquent like so: `DB::connection('sqlsrv')->select($query)` I get the error `The active result for the query contains no fields.`

Background: I'm creating an app that ensures certain queries result in a valid result set for reporting purposes. Mostly these ara data mappings for free text input to a defined list of options. If a new free text entry is found in the production a query should mention the unmapped value(s) so I can add them to the defined table.

I have no writing access on the production database, only read. Creating stored procedures is not an option due to this limitation. When I copy the query to SQL Server Management Studio it works like charm. I'm guessing this is because SSMS internally seperates the results and Eloquent doesn't.

How can I get a query like the given one get to work with Eloquent?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by the tag [common-table-expression]? Common Table Expressions (CTEs) weren't introduced until SQL Server 2008

Comment: I assumed declaring a table was also a common table expression? Maybe I'm wrong about that. If so, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Try setting `SET NOCOUNT ON;` before your query to prevent mssql from returning the affected row count which may be interpreted as a resultset with _no fields_

Answer (score 0):

Pure guesswork, but does eloquent require column names ?

Try

```
Select distinct(lookup_field) as lookup_field
```

Comment: Good point, but unfortunately I also experience the same when I try a query like `declare @mytable table(id int, name varchar(255)) insert into @table values (1, 'test') select * from @table results`. Which implies it's not a column naming issue.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried the command below on my Tinker and it worked fine.
Remember to include "SET NOCOUNT ON" and format to use just one line.

```
DB::connection()->select("SET NOCOUNT ON; declare @mapping_table table(id int, name varchar(255), mapping_value varchar(255)); insert into @mapping_table values (1, 'foo', 'A1'); insert into @mapping_table values (2, 'bar', 'A1'); insert into @mapping_table values (3, 'baz', 'A2'); select distinct lookup_field from production_table where lookup_field not in (select name  from @mapping_table)");
```