# Is there a way to put a query result in memory and reference it in another query?

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, in-memory

I'm facing difficulties with PDO and a SqlSrv connection that uses a common table expression to create an in-memory table that is referenced by the query that should produce the query output. More over the issue can be read in a question about that I posted earlier today: [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36743040/eloquent-with-common-table-expressions).

Say I have this query:

```
-- app.use("Dummy Foo Bar Baz table")

/**
 * The above line is a custom made syntax that lets me include
 * common SQL parts I need often in different queries.
 */

select * from @table
```

Using `preg_match_all` I search for all `-- app.use("(.*)")` usages. In the background this simply checks a table with predefined queries for a name-column with the given name and includes that SQL to the query to be executed. In this case, the SQL for "Dummy Foo Bar Baz table" is:

```
declare @table table(id int, name varchar(255))

insert into @table values (1, 'foo')
insert into @table values (2, 'bar')
insert into @table values (3, 'baz')
```

The complete query that is fired to the SQL Server database is:

```
declare @table table(id int, name varchar(255))

insert into @table values (1, 'foo')
insert into @table values (2, 'bar')
insert into @table values (3, 'baz')

select * from @table
```

When I run this I get an `The active result for the query contains no fields` error. The query runs fine in SQL Server Management Studio. I believe this is caused because SSMS internally handles or saves the CTE result in memory and PDO doesn't support this or at least ignores to do it for the moment.

**Alternative approach to get the result from the above query**

So I was wondering if it would be possible to break it down, without rebuilding a SQL intepreter but to execute all `app.use(..)` and store them in memory (or at a place where it resides so I can reference it) and use them for the "final" query `select * from @table`.

The user for the database I'm querying has read-only access (and it's not possible to change the permissions), so stored procedures are not the solution.

Can this be done?

Comment: I forgot to mention I only have read permissions on the database I'm quering. I'll update the question.

Comment: MYSQL or SQL Server, which one?

Comment: Target database is SQL Server. I'll remove mysql tag. The includable queries are stored in a MySQL server (different server and part of a Laravel app I'm crafting to get this stuff to work).